# Как можно сделать перемотку слайдера мышкой(либо пальцем на телефоне) на радио кнопках?

Tags: html, css, slider, radiobutton

У меня есть слайдер на чистом html через radio кнопки. Он будет отображаться только на мобильных устройствах, и по кнопках не очень удобно переключать? Можно ли как то сделать чтобы была возможность листать пальцем(влево и вправо) на этих радио кнопках, или нужно полностью переделывать?

[Ссылка на код](https://codepen.io/Kaidos/pen/BamxyKW)

```css
.slider_body{
    
}

.slider {
    width: 450px;
    height: 390px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.slider__nav {
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  margin: 2rem 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.slider__nav:checked {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(1) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: 0%;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(2) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -100%;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(3) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -200%;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(4) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -300%;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(5) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -400%;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(6) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -500%;
}
.slider__nav:checked:nth-of-type(7) ~ .slider__inner {
    left: -600%;
}
.slider__inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 700%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.4s;
  transition: left 0.4s;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
          flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.slider__contents {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
      -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
    user-select: none;
}

.slider_circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 53deg, rgb(24,34,99) 0%, rgb(18,32,124) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 53deg, rgb(24,34,99) 0%, rgb(18,32,124) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 53deg, rgb(24,34,99) 0%, rgb(18,32,124) 100%);
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    position: relative;
}

.slider_circle svg{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.slider__contents p.advantage_title{
    margin-top: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_body">


  <div class="container">

    <p class="block_header">Наши преимущества</p>

    <div class="slider">

      <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide1" checked="checked" class="slider__nav"/>
      <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide2" class="slider__nav"/>
      <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide3" class="slider__nav"/>
      <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide4" class="slider__nav"/>
      <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide5" class="slider__nav"/>
      <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide6" class="slider__nav"/>
      <input type="radio" name="slider" title="slide7" class="slider__nav"/>

      <div class="slider__inner">

        <div class="slider__contents">

          <div class="slider_circle">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="53" height="49" viewBox="0 0 53 49">
              <image id="experts_icon" data-name="experts icon" width="53" height="49" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADUAAAAxCAYAAAB6d+FmAAAHNUlEQVRogc1aC7BOVRT+XKL0uNRNXQwpJZIZepmMnoNILxQ9iZTeKY/pwVSmogyphEapUTS9ZiL0IpFQUpRQ08P0UFJUKKW+Ztd3Ztbd9vn3OeO/d1oz++7/rL3W2mudffZaa699QbIqWmeSX5E8uyrmq+b+VAF8CaAxgPUA6lf2dCVVYNC5MshBOYCLK3vCqlipTwE0BbBOxrn+oMqcsLJWqhTA0QBuk0E/6PlrGTZCz3UqZfYibtCeJOeSXEPyd1aEYaIZ5OG3k1xLch7JC/+PjmItgMPMs/vMNgBYAmAQgD8A1ABwH4DjARxg9pqDrwA0KoomRVypViTXawU+I9kwQn8AyU9E/wPJo4qlS7FjRDnJDVL0PZK1U+h2J7lEdJtINiqmHlmIJpC8KYfQ+iRXSeEPSVYL0Lyj8TU5DXJ7c/yuGnWW2dT75Zi8k3h+Thn/TuNn5JDZwOhySiHamEt/wPwelWOrNlA/QX0LAEMBtNLzePV5soux5vf4AnRBo5IYc6fnjfoBuEAK7h5RoK36bQCGA1gFYCSAFQDuAPCXxttF5NQG0BJAH2UmCRwO4BYARwHYZycus2xHai/84sWS3iQf9HDOGSwiWZryCSzhzvBOALc8hb9M9Bs9+lEkr/Bwm0muJNk0tKdO8Ihnkhyjsb3lMHzFygIKVfdo5po90J7kK974bgEZDT2aRZq/hsbHkZzt0bRJcxQXGKJ7ApO9prEtJJunvOUSkrO0Cp1SaE4luUzyqqfQtCb5l+abERgfZ3StcKQJCTtPXquC9TLSwackm+XwWrvSjiH5heYdauScKNyPJM/M4v2eAfCr224A9gRwFYCuOgs5eEUpUVXAuwDmax6XFHcDcLnSLQffApjh6xHK/cpFvAPAZgBlwn8O4GAAS413ywLObbcBUA/ATwA+0KExKzjP2cLM7+A7yYP025Tm/ZJ2urcB3yX5TQYHEZIzl2FYTLJXBhmHetzuU3zfw53s84UEJV7QRf2rhNtN7jSBehFlxnsTr9TxYrmHn57RqB0kRxj8DSR/0tjRWYyCMu69AviDbTxIac8bpUcEcjuXnQ8xNIsi8g5PyQ/rKrbuxFNsb9XPKNslQtvWHCbvKKYexTTIrew2KXlZRp7O5iU0KJYuWWoUeynXKo/QdQewB4BPAEzO6NnmAJin370jtPtLj2hdo5BRHQG8LLe+Wm7eudfBKfQnqJ8Um9SD5AWcnDI+AMB7Kg2slvt+Uy8xDClLeJvnpTZ7z/OVDlmeBRrrlvNzSbKDNYGxF715N3nP92fdUzb/m6SUyBlQRy4+2dyveXxvCN89p1EniW+1h59i9BiiMOL0aEzyXjM2NGbUnooJDoanKNGC5N+isYnkw8INy2nUpeKbaXBtjdIubob4LktzMj7h+SL6MqLIXQFFugm3PqdRSUC+1uAmC/dIhHex6AYW8n7N1T8Z2dzJeEuDc4nljwAOBDAso5NwJ9rWSp6fMvikfvhshP9x9UdapG9U8vx7RNgO9TU8XOKWXSngmoiMXgCm6PeVSnZ9Pf6MyEjGq1ukb9QX6ntGhHVV7x9BZpkCyYMApgFor1gHxbFj5fanCzctEAbWqe8c0aNHUA/vGy0zm693yndcauoYfVNobvVc71Z5Nz80jEnhP03jLkNpkkLT0cipcGgNEdtkczDJfbzJPtPYx5FN7Iy/huSbniFLdVFQHuF/XfTudNvD4Gt6xZeHYi49FCO2KrCuNThn2P4RpWoqBk3S1aiD70lOVbKbVpJOWi3v7LROL8hWmEK1i4IJbQcdI3YYIa5Ycn1EGRdjnmM2eFXzFJLnMv+FnrTZhTKXGsHt9x8sA7BQl2atVCOwNYMQjANwncHP0fH/Y7n7ukpKXRHyHAAd1KYC6A9ge0DmWwo17vaxoW4m31YLQ8DSdiTnRN7zN9oXCc8eJvejgmbLyAo4BzDa8KzyTtQDzP5Ng4Xa5wU/vxs95heULvXVEXqiN9ESldFe1vNvKbW+I0iOJXl8YOwYc6/1kep9M8wcbuxR3bw4PW4m+TTJPw3NPWlG3W6IHotcsVxkaoMJbFdeGKIfLpon9OxW5BIlycnzeu4MA0xV1m9lCgkJTPSN6mIGB0Q+GxhF5hu+9gVo3TVQH/OihplVSD5TWzlyhZpDMupxruHrnxhV3QTTuzMKSto08U3IyddMcY4KsHWFHyrcgpzyrjaGlUL1Nwff5hTUxAgKVZ5izb3MFeKfZQ6dWzKsfKgl2f6QEiWWDu6N5Fk+XKLn2QC25OSF7qiS3K6LqYFMVX9hTnkj1fcoMRdfi3MKaaP+pZx8Flzdo68u4jYIP1d9qzh7BVia8LlaelJML9G5Jiss0v9DuMk/3AXDfNhXgXqjKkh54F/9bUYxWoX3rHCc6AaqylMsOFByXOH/Vv1TSRaolRC5lXJnF5e+7J1TKTeZS2vy8mUBd5Xkvhx3lZSPD9j8D1e4SZiS9670AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/>
            </svg>  

          </div>

          <p class="advantage_title">Укомплектованный штат экспертов<br>
            <span>доктора и кандидаты наук,<br> 
              инженеры и проектировщики</span></p>

        </div>

        <div class="slider__contents">

          <div class="slider_circle">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="47" height="47" viewBox="0 0 47 47">
              <image id="recommendations_icon" data-name="recommendations icon" width="47" height="47" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
            </svg>

          </div>

          <p class="advantage_title">Рекомендации специалистов<br> 
            и экспертов </p>

        </div>

        <div class="slider__contents">
          <div class="slider_circle">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="61" height="60" viewBox="0 0 61 60">
              <image id="russia_icon" data-name="russia icon" width="61" height="60" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
            </svg>  

          </div>

          <p class="advantage_title">Работа со всеми регионами<br> 
            Российской Федерации</p>

        </div>

        <div class="slider__contents">

          <div class="slider_circle">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
              <image id="economy_icon" data-name="economy icon" width="50" height="50" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
            </svg>

          </div>

          <p class="advantage_title">Экономим до 30% бюджета проекта<br>
            <span>Подключаемся на любом этапе</span></p>

        </div>

        <div class="slider__contents">

          <div class="slider_circle">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="47" height="47" viewBox="0 0 47 47">
              <image id="recommendations_icon" data-name="recommendations icon" width="47" height="47" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
            </svg>

          </div>

          <p class="advantage_title">Рекомендации специалистов<br> 
            и экспертов </p>

        </div>

        <div class="slider__contents">
          <div class="slider_circle">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="61" height="60" viewBox="0 0 61 60">
              <image id="russia_icon" data-name="russia icon" width="61" height="60" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
            </svg>  

          </div>

          <p class="advantage_title">Работа со всеми регионами<br> 
            Российской Федерации</p>

        </div>

        <div class="slider__contents">

          <div class="slider_circle">

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
              <image id="economy_icon" data-name="economy icon" width="50" height="50" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
            </svg>

          </div>

          <p class="advantage_title">Экономим до 30% бюджета проекта<br>
            <span>Подключаемся на любом этапе</span></p>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Изучите данный слайдер. Надеюст помог вам

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  
  
  
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  
  /*
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  */
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
.slides > div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.slides > div:target {
/*   transform: scale(0.8); */
}
.author-info {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.author-info a {
  color: white;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider > a {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
}
.slider > a:active {
  top: 1px;
}
.slider > a:focus {
  background: #000;
}

@supports (scroll-snap-type) {
  .slider > a {
    display: none;
  }
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #74ABE2, #5563DE);
  font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  
  <a href="#slide-1">1</a>
  <a href="#slide-2">2</a>
  <a href="#slide-3">3</a>
  <a href="#slide-4">4</a>
  <a href="#slide-5">5</a>

  <div class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div id="slide-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div id="slide-3">
      3
    </div>
    <div id="slide-4">
      4
    </div>
    <div id="slide-5">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Поддержка](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-snap) *шикарная*